# Electric heating element inside refractory concrete

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, heat-transfer

I'm thinking of making an electric pizza oven in my free time. My thinking at the moment is to have one kilowatt electric heating elements in the bottom as well as the top of pizza oven. I would like even heat all over the chamber of the oven. I've been thinking about casting electric heating elements inside refractory concrete. I would control the temperature using a PID controller and an embedded thermocouple. Both top and bottom would have individual control. The slabs themselves would probably be quite thin (15-20 mm) and the whole thing will be thermally isolated before being placed in a steel box. Target temperature would be 300 to 350 degrees Celsius.

Heating element I'm considering is similar to this type:
[image: Heating element]

**The question is:** can I embed the heating elements inside the concrete slab? Will there be problems like the element's surface temperature getting too hot before the surrounding concrete starts to sink the heat? Perhaps thermal expansion and contraction will crack the slab over time? Is the heating element type shown above "compatible" with the concrete or will they corrode over time? Some other thing I did not think of?

Comment: The standard heating elements are Inconel ( 601) sheath with Nichrome wire insulated with magnesium oxide. Nichrome is very similar to Inconel. By over-heating the sheath with insulating refractory there is a risk of "hot corrosion" ; Which is specific to the components in the refractory.  Caustic ( NaO, KO, etc )can cause it , there will be others that I do not recall. These heating elements are designed to have some amount of heat dissipation with no insulation.

Comment: I forgot to mention the Nichrome wire in the sheath is hotter than the sheath and will melt at some point if heat is not dissipated.

Comment: One thing to think about is that by embedding the coil rather than exposing it directly, you are losing out on a lot of radiant heating that would otherwise be there

Comment: If the heating element consists of wiring in a metal conduit, the heat can cause debonding the conduit from the concrete due to incompatible thermal conductivity. For such a thin concrete, I doubt the viability of such a setup.

Comment: Yes @RC_23 you're quite right, and that will then boil your pizza instead of baking it. Radiant heat plays fundamental role in good cooking.

Comment: Excellent points. So it seems I fundamentally need to rethink my plan. For baking a pizza I think it's okay to have just conducting heat but for top it's good to have radiant heat as well. So perhaps an exposed heating element on the surface of the concrete block. For bottom... perhaps the same setup but also a slab on top to bake the pizza on top of?